# How to get an Image from S3 with AWS Amplify and render it in React-Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

I have the following code:

```
 await Storage.get('120.png', {
  level: 'protected',
  bucket: 'pictures-bucket-*****',
  region: '**',
})
  .then(result => {
    this.setState({url: result});

    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And in render:

```
 <Image
      style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
      source={{uri: this.state.url}}
    />
```

This brings me some sort of URL but the  component doesn't render it at all.

Is there anything special needs to be done with the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem here was in the access rights for my Cognito users.

You can modify the access rights in the Cognito user panel and allow access to the needed bucket.

But for me, it still only works with "level: 'protected'"